# Is there any way to read a file input and text input from request object, which is passed as multipart form-data passed to loopback2 POST API?

Tags: node.js, post, multipartform-data, loopback

I have to set up a POST API in loopback2, which accepts a file input and text input together
When inputting it as multipart form-data, I am not able to read it from inside the API.

[Here is how the request look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2S6r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use multer package [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Multer is a node.js middleware for handling multipart/form-data and you can easily view all  formdata parameters.

Comment: Welcome. Please up vote, if the above solution helped you out.